# Relating Line and Circle Topologies

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to develop a better conceptual understanding for how a topology endows shape to a space.  Contrasting discrete (too many open sets so points too far from each other), Hausdorff (just enough open sets so points are separated enough to be distinguishable but not so much that limits aren't well-behaved), and trivial (not enough open sets so points all collapse on top of each other) topologies is really helpful but I'd like to go one step further and understand how certain open sets can take the same ambient set into a line and a circle.

More formally let $X$ be an uncountably infinite set and consider two compact, Hausdorff topologies $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ such that $(X, \tau_{1})$ is homeomorphic to a finite real line interval and $(X, \tau_{2})$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$.  Is there any general intuition about the open sets in $\tau_{1} \setminus \tau_{2}$ and $\tau_{2} \setminus \tau_{1}$?

In other words what open sets have to be added and removed from the line topology $\tau_{1}$ in order to modify it into the circle topology $\tau_{2}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Just take any bijection between a line segment and a circle. Hint: they are not nice, but not too scary either.

Comment: A Hausdorff topology can have 'enough open sets that it isn't well behaved'. The discrete topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: If you take the standard topology on $[0,1)$ and remove all the open sets which contain $0$ but for any $\varepsilon >0$ don't contain $(1-\varepsilon,1)$, you're essentially joining the ends, and get the circle topology. You're essentially forcing any open neighbourhood of $0$ to continue a little bit onto the other side, so that it loops around rather than acting like an endpoint.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Thanks, this is great.  Does one have to _add_ any open sets, though?  My understanding is that both $\tau_{1} \setminus \tau_{2}$ and $\tau_{2} \setminus \tau_{1}$ have to be non-empty in order for both topologies to be Hausdorff.

Comment: That's not true. For example the discrete topology is Hausdorff, but every other topology on the same set is a subset of it. Also, any refinement of a Hausdorff topology is also Hausdorff. No sets need to be added.

Comment: Ah, apologies for being sloppy I forget to explicitly mention the compactness of the circle.  If $\tau_{2}$ is compact Hausdorff then it can't be a refinement of a Hausdorff topology like $\tau_{1}$, no?  Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up that my confusion arose from messing up the directionally of refinement/corsenings.  The circle is compact Hausdorff and any refinement loses compactness while maintaining Hausdorff separability but that's fine because the half-open interval is indeed not compact.  Corsening the circle would lose Hausdorff separability but that's irrelevant to the comparison here.  Thanks again and apologies for my mistake!